# iOS : DNS SRV lookup using DNSServiceQueryRecord

Tags: ios, dns, srv

I plan to use apple's DNSServiceQueryRecord to resolve SRV records. I see that the callback passed to this method is called once per record that is returned from SRV lookup. How do i know that the query has completed and all the records have been returned?

Apple's documentation for your reference.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Networking/Reference/DNSServiceDiscovery_CRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/DNSServiceQueryRecord

Comment: The query runs indefinitely until you terminate it, as new services could appear at any time.  You need to decide when you have "enough" answers.  This could be after you have 1 answer, after a period of time or when the user/app exits your discovery view

Comment: quick question to be totally sure : is this a blocking or non-blocking method?

Comment: non-blocking.  That is why it has the callback function

Comment: Thanks for the inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to point out the method "DNSServiceProcessResult" to process the DNS result is blocking. I used select() to look if there is data received in the socket to call DNSServiceProcessResult. This makes the method unblocking. I check if there is data in socket for 2 seconds and if i don't get back any results, I cancel the query.

Comment: This works for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22502729/resolving-srv-records-with-ios-sdk

Answer by @meaning-matters